# Assigning values for a scorecard

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics

I am generating a scorecard with the KPIs being scored from a scale of 1 - 5, 5 being the highest and 1 as the lowest. One of the KPIs is billable hours and I have a dataset from billable hours from last year and Q1 of this year. The mean of the data set is 60 and the standard deviation is 30. I can't figure out what values to assign between 1 - 5 to ensure a normal distribution in a bell curve. Would appreciate if the excel formula is provided. I'm not very good in statistics and math but I can figure it out with an explanation and samples. Thanks!

Comment: Note, with your mean of 60 and sd of 30 your data really wouldn't fit a normal distribution. Simply, if you are dealing with anything below 2 standard deviations your in negative hours, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Getting that out of the way, I think you can still transform your data into your 5 point scale. You just have to define what what that means. So is a 5 lots of billable hours or does it mean "right amount" of billable hours? I think once you answer this you can see a way to scale your billable hours to your KPI range. Maybe a utilization rate would be a better measure...

Comment: You can try to provide a simple sample here.